# Managing Path With rbenv

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages, rbenv

I installed rbenv to manage my ruby installations, and then I subsequently ran `gem install github-pages` to get `jekyll` and other dependencies needed for developing a github pages site. However, now when I try to run the `jekyll` command I get

```
The program 'jekyll' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt-get install jekyll
```

I assume this is a path issue, but I thought the path was supposed to be handled by rbenv. I also previously had the same issue when completing the same process using RVM instead of rbenv. How can I fix this?

I just tried running `gem env` and got the following:

```
RubyGems Environment:


- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/daniel/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/daniel/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
     - /home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin
     - /home/daniel/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/daniel/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/daniel/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/daniel/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/daniel/.rbenv/bin
     - /opt/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
     - /home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin
     - /home/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /home/daniel/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: If `rbenv` is installed correctly then the `shims` directory should be in your path. It's possible this is missing. Be sure the `rbenv` stub sigil including `$(rbenv init -)` is loaded into your `.bash_profile` or wherever that is supposed to be.

Comment: Yes, I have that in my `.bashrc` already...so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Does `echo $PATH` show the `shims` directory? Either that's missing, or the stub for `jekyll` wasn't installed correctly for whatever reason. The stub should be in whatever path `$PATH` shows.

Comment: Yes, it shows `/home/daniel/.rbenv/shims` in my path. I'm having the same issue with other gems I installed such as `bundler`. The installation was successful but they are not showing as installed.

Comment: Is there a stub for `jekyll` in that directory? If not, maybe your `gem` program is installing them in the incorrect location. As an idea, maybe a shims extension like [rbenv-binstubs](https://github.com/ianheggie/rbenv-binstubs) might help.

Comment: I think I found the issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Please take a look at my edited question. Should I just copy `/home/daniel/.rmv/gems` to `/home/daniel/.rbenv/bin`?

Comment: No, there's a big difference between where the gem is installed to (`gems`) and where the binary stub is installed (`shims`). The two are not the same. Does creating a new window/shell solve the problem? Rebooting? Do other gems have the same problem, like Rails or anything convenient with a command-line tool?

Comment: You can not run RVM and rbenv at the same time or you'll find Cthulhu inhabiting your system. The rbenv documentation is very specific about that: "rbenv is incompatible with RVM. Please make sure to fully uninstall RVM and remove any references to it from your shell initialization files before installing rbenv."

Comment: @theTinMan I thought I had removed RVM, but somehow I missed that .rvm directory. I have now deleted that, but for some reason the directory is still in my `$PATH` even though I moved the offending lines from my `.bash_rc`,  `.bash_profile` and `.profile`

Comment: @tadman rebooting the computer seems to have altered the `GEM_PATH` variable in my gem env so I guess I'll try reinstalling the gems.

Answer (score 1):

You have both rbenv and RVM installed and running at the same time. Don't do that.

Per [the rbenv documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv):

> Compatibility note: rbenv is incompatible with RVM. Please make sure to fully uninstall RVM and remove any references to it from your shell initialization files before installing rbenv.

The why to that delves into how the shell finds commands which would be off-topic. You can research that if you're so inclined.

> Should I just copy /home/daniel/.rmv/gems to /home/daniel/.rbenv/bin?

No.

"just copy" would run the risk of havoc breaking loose farther down the road.

I'd recommend temporarily disabling rbenv by commenting-out its initialization in your ~/.bash_profile, then restart your terminal session resulting in only RVM being available. Then run

```
gem list --no-versions > ~/rvm-gems-list
```

Then reenable rbenv by removing the comment mark, and comment-out the RVM initialization and restart your terminal session to give rbenv control. Run

```
xargs gem install --conservative < ~/rvm-gems-list
```

which will spin through all the gems installed in your RVM instance and let gem install any that are missing. Once that finishes you can delete the rvm-gems-list file:

```
rm ~/rvm-gems-list
```

At this point you need to remove RVM, or toggle back and forth between rbenv and RVM by alternately enabling/disabling them as you did above. You can't have them both running at the same time, and trying to remember where gems are installed will be a pain so I'd suggest sticking with one or the other.

(I use them both, only on separate systems.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed your steps, and couldn't run `gem list` which verified that `RVM` was uninstalled. I think the issue was that when I uninstalled `RVM` the `GEM_PATH` was not modified accordingly. I deleted the `.rvm` directory and fixed the `GEM_PATH` variable and reinstalled all gems, and this seems to have fixed things. I still need to figure out how to remove `.rvm` from my path though. It is not listed in any of the bashrc or bash_profile files, so I can't figure out why it's still in the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: You don't say how you deleted RVM. `rvm implode` is the correct way, however you can simply do `rm -rf ~/.rvm` and then remove the initialization commands from ~/.bash_profile. Once the initialization is removed, restart your shell and RVM should be gone from the path. If it's not look for PATH manipulations in your ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc. In general I prefer rbenv because it's simple. (RVM is powerful but I've seen it go nuts in the past; I've been using it since it was first written.)